# What does AFK mean?

Tags: terminology

I have heard my friend talk about being AFK on a Minecraft server, but I have not heard it being used in single player so I assume it refers to online gaming but i don't know what it means and what it stands for.

Comment: I did not downvote but I just want to say that I think it is a bad question because it shows poor research. just googling "What does AFK mean?" would give your answer very fast. Questions on stackexchange should only be posted if you couldn't find it easily via google or some other way.

Comment: Right now, googling "What does AFK mean?" gets you the answer from this page, shown right on the google results page. So, while I agree that this question shows a lack of research, it makes it so future googlers have an easier time. So overall, a positive thing, I think.

Comment: This question makes me feel old. I remember asking it in the 80s when I logged on to the only BBS in town that had enough phone lines to host a chat room for the first time. :(

Comment: @TimS. That's because Google ranks the StackExchange network highly on their search results. Also, "What does AFK mean?" is a very specific term, that quickly matches with the title given. Just searching for "AFK" makes this page appear on the bottom of the 3rd page. It's positive, sure, but it's also a lack of research, considering Wikipedia or even the OP's friend could have told him about it.

Comment: @IvoBeckers Completely agree and that's why I AM downvoting... -1

Comment: This question is the very definition of lack of research.  -1

Comment: @TimS. - that is what it shows YOU, but not others - try it in a fresh browser or after clearing cookies (prior to visiting this page in said browser) - it's just Google tracking where you have been and altering the results it shows based on that knowledge.

Comment: @user2813274 That's a useful tip in general, but does not appear to be the case here. Unless they're tracking my IP to know my history or location and use that knowledge. Doktoro's objection is more relevant: not many will search for *exactly* "What does AFK mean?". Most other forms, like "define afk", return a result from dictionary.com, e.g.

Comment: @TimS. It's not just a useful tip, it applies to everyone. If you visit this site, then it pushes this very link up to the search bar. Had you gone to google before going to SE, and searched up AFK, you would have found a far more comprehensive answer elsewhere

Answer (score 58, accepted):

AFK is an acronym for "away from keyboard".

It's commonly used in multiplayer games and chat rooms to let other players know that you will be unavailable for a short time (away from keyboard), or to quickly explain an idle period.

Comment: it's also used for online console games which don't have a keyboard, for the same historical reasons that a floppy drive is used as a save icon

Comment: came here to say that. Here, get your +1 :)

Comment: While you're "away from keyboard", you may also be "a free kill"

Answer (score 18):

Well, I'm ***a***​way ***f***​rom my ***k***​eyboard right now.

I'll tell you when I get back.

Comment: Jeez. For shame!

Comment: SCNR​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Voice typing OP, nerf please.

Comment: @WhynoTalos I didn't mean to offend. I was just pointing out a grammatical curiosity (intended to be interpreted lightly): You said "I'm a​way f​rom my k​eyboard right now", which may imply that you did not use a keyboard to type that phrase. A common non-keyboard solution for typing is voice recognition software. Sorry if I sounded harsh, English is my second language.

Comment: @Kroltan Point taken. I type directly over the ether with my brain. :D

Comment: If your away from your keyboard, how did you type that?

Comment: @Oreo See my above comment.

Answer (score 13):

AFK simply means **A**way **F**rom **K**eyboard. It's commonly used in chatrooms and online games and it basically means that you won't be available (Not at the keyboard = Not in front of your computer).

Just in case you're wondering what RE or WB means: You'll see these two abbreviations quite often in onlinegames together with AFK. **Re** which basically means **Re**turned and WB which stands for **W**elcome **B**ack.

Comment: Bk, short for back, is also regularly used. Although the full word back is common, since it's so short.

Comment: Also, **B**e **R**ight **B**ack.

Comment: If you say "back" when you return from AFK and someone says "front" you are required to "lol". It's an internet tradition.

Comment: @BrianDHall If someone says `ping`, you MUST say `pong`.

Answer (score 6):

AFK is used (as you correctly assumed) online. Like many other used words online (like *lol* and *gtg* etc.) AFK is a abbreviation, specifically for ***A*** way ***F*** rom ***K*** eyboard.

Answer (score 5):

AFK is an acronym for Away From Keyboard. Say, you have to go for a break, then you write AFK in your private/public chatroom. Used in mobile texting and instant messaging as well.