# What is the meaning of DLC?

Tags: terminology

I hear and see in the gaming community this term a lot. Even in questions here in Arqade

**What does it mean?**

**What are some examples of DLC?**

Comment: I dont believe I deserve the flag/downvote

Comment: Typing 'video game dlc' into a Google search would show the wiki page that is linked in the accepted answer as the first hit.  Below that are multiple lists of 'Best DLCs for ***' Questions that show little or no research effort should be down-voted.

Comment: The comments [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/189559/what-does-afk-mean) are pretty applicable.  While we won't close the question (or at least, I won't), asking a question that is this easily googled should be expected to gather downvotes for lack of prior research.

Comment: @Lokuzt For why lack of research has led to you getting downvotes, hover over the downvote arrow - it says it right there.

Comment: But still I don't see any difference from this answer to someone asking for PvP and getting no hate and 11 upvotes. It is ALL Searching. I thought I could ask here if there was more to it and someone would point out interesting things as they always do. But I guess I get struck with hate this day.

Comment: @Lokuzt To be blunt, this is exactly why there's a tiny rep hit for getting downvoted: it will discourage you from posting a question with a blatant lack of research in the future. But it's not going to keep getting downvoted forever, and each downvote's only -2 rep - you can balance out five of them with two upvote. Another question with a few upvotes will make up for this.

Comment: Or it could be that we expect users to make an attempt to answer the question on their own.  While we will certainly help with questions that demonstrate a lack of research, you shouldn't expect it to be accepted with open arms.  Remember, the experts like interesting questions.  Asking what DLC means isn't that, at all.  It's a super simple term, easily found.  And generally, complaining about downvotes tend to draw more of them your way.  I suspect at least a few are due to that.

Comment: @Cascabel You can get auto-banned for receiving too many downvotes on your questions; they are certainly not inconsequential.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

DLC means [Downloadable Content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downloadable_content):

> Downloadable content can be of several types, ranging from aesthetic outfit changes to a new, extensive storyline, similar to an expansion pack. As such, DLC may add new game modes, objects, levels, challenges or other features to a complete and already released game.

Comment: "Reversal" badge for this…

Answer (score 8):

Most probably they are talking about: **D**own**L**oadable **C**ontent

such as addons or software expansions.

please see the wiki : [DLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downloadable_content)