# What specifically does "Leet" or 1337 mean?

Tags: terminology

I know this is a dumb question, but what exactly does the term **Leet** or **1337** mean and where did it originate?

Comment: This reminds me of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190791/what-is-the-meaning-of-dlc).  While we will accept questions of such basic terms, don't expect it to be very well received.

Comment: On the plus side, this page is the first result when googling "[What does 1337 mean?](http://i.imgur.com/8ENSC6k.png)"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Leet (or "1337"), also known as eleet or leetspeak, is an alternative
>   alphabet for the English language that is used primarily on the
>   Internet. It uses various combinations of ASCII characters to replace
>   Latinate letters. For example, leet spellings of the word leet include
>   1337 and l33t; eleet may be spelled 31337 or 3l33t.  The term leet is
>   derived from the word elite. The leet alphabet is a specialized form
>   of symbolic writing.
>
> Leet originated within bulletin board systems (BBS) in the 1980s,
>   where having "elite" status on a BBS allowed a user access to file
>   folders, games, and special chat rooms.

Taken from [the Wikipedia page for LEET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leet)

Comment: For reference, [Here's each letter and it's leetspeak equivalents](https://qntm.org/l33t)